# When installing with Yarn, is the lock of all dependencies checked also?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

When installing packages via Yarn, will it get locked versions of dependencies of dependencies?

e.g. I have a `package.json` + lock in the root which contains package A which also contains a lock. Will Yarn now consider both locks? Or only the root lock? And is it possible to tell Yarn to ignore level 2 locks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only the top-level `Yarn.lock` file is considered**.

> During install Yarn will only use the top-level yarn.lock file and will ignore any yarn.lock files that exist within dependencies. The top-level yarn.lock file includes everything Yarn needs to lock the versions of all packages in the entire dependency tree.

([Yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/#toc-current-package-only))

You don't need to tell Yarn to ignore lower-level lock files, because it already does that. The `Yarn.lock` file is a **single** source for all dependency information — they aren't processed recursively.